# Does Solder selection affect signal quality?

Tags: audio, soldering

I've been wanting to design some circuits for audio processing. I am curious if solder plays a part in retaining signal quality. Is an exotic material or high end lead based solder worth it? Does it even make a difference? How would I objectively measure this?

Comment: Audiophiles reckon Tantalum resistors make all the difference so if you asked this question to one of those folk I'm sure they'd be adamant that it does!!

Comment: *lead* based? I would have thought audiophiles insisted on *gold* based solder.

Comment: A question of this type should always be of the form "does X *significantly* affect y".  The point, of course, is that yes, solder "makes a difference" but the real question is "to what degree?".  Most (all?) audiophiles would do better to invest in acoustic treatments of their listening room which offer *far, far* more significant difference than solder (properly done, of course).

Comment: I can't tell if this is a real engineering question or a audiphool religious one.  Note that the second is off topic here.

Answer (score 7):

I work in both the Pro-Audio and audiophile industry.  As long as the solder is used properly, and makes a solid connection, then the type of solder makes zero impact in audio quality.

The flux inside the solder, on the other hand, can make a big impact.  But here too, if used properly, it won't matter.  Basically, clean off the flux that is supposed to be cleaned off.  Some flux is fine if not cleaned up.  Rosin and "no clean" flux is fine left on there (mostly).

Answer (score 3):

Stick to 60:40 Sn-Pb solder. It is easy to work with, and has the nice property that good joints look shiny.  Solder is several times more resistive than copper. However, the distances spanned by solder are very tiny.

When soldering, try to ensure contact between the parts being soldered, if possible. Sometimes the contact is poor to nonexistent, like between the terminal of a through-hole device and the PCB copper pad through which it protrudes, particularly if it is one-sided PCB without plated holes. However, the distance is still very close, so the bridge formed by solder is very short.

In audio circuits, the impedances tend to be high. The tiny fraction of an ohm added by a bead of solder to a circuit in which the impedance is 10,000 ohms makes no difference.

Even in a power amplifier output stage where the impedances are a lot smaller, it doesn't matter. Consider that it's common to degenerate the emitter resistors of a complementary pair emitter follower with 0.22 ohm resistors which are effectively in series with the speaker load. Even these small 0.22 ohm resistors will swamp the resistance of their own solder joints.

(Some audiophiles will no doubt try to convince you that the junction between solder and copper causes distortion that is audible to one who possesses golden ears.)

Answer (score 2):

Lead solder works fine (though it does eventually crystallize; after around 40 years it's worth reflowing every joint!) but an unqualified recommendation to use it is bad advice. If you are building equipment for your own use, or for sale in those parts of the world where it is still allowed, go ahead.

But if you live elsewhere or aspire to selling worldwide (not so ambitious since eBay started!) then look for lead-free alternatives. Some of these contain a small percentage of silver; it may not make any difference to the sound but it it may be worth a minor selling point.